# Выражение xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="union.xsl"?>
<root>
   <y>
      <x>blue</x>
      <z>red</z>
   </y>
   <y>
      <x>yellow</x>
   </y>
</root>
```

Можно ли как-то с помощью XPath выбрать только те узлы `x`, которые находятся внутри `y`, содержащих `z`? В данном случае один тег `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо использовать запрос `y[z]/x`.